# Javascript disable container, but enable inputs in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="section_rows">
    <div class="body-row crew">
        <input type="text" class="col1" name="cast_person" value="{{cast.person }}"/>
        <input type="text" class="col2" name="cast_character" value="{{ cast.character }}"/>
        <input class="ordering" type="hidden" name="cast_ordering" value="{{ cast.ordering }}" />
        <a href="#;" class="delete">X</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
// drag and drop of cast and crew
$('.section_rows').sortable();
$( ".section_rows" ).disableSelection();
```

Currently, this disables the entire `section_rows` div container. How would I enabled the `input`s inside it?

Comment: Should be noted it's deprecated since version 1.9 with this note: _"Disabling text selection is bad. Don't use this."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use `handle` option of draggable to only use an element within the container to drag with. Best solution will depend on your UI but this can be a helpful solution. Then don't worry about calling `disableSelection()`

Answer (score 1):

Quite obvious I believe:

```
$( ".section_rows" ).disableSelection().find('input').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: @David542, I never used it, but I believe it should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$('.selection_rows :not(input)').disableSelection();
```